# An inverse definite integral problem

Tags: integral-transforms, integral-equations

I am seeking a function $f(x)$ that satisfies this condition: 
$\int_{0}^{\infty }f(x)x^ndx=\sqrt{n!}$ where n is an integer. I guess that $f$ will contain $e^{-\alpha x^2}$ as one of its factors, where $\alpha$ is some fraction.

Comment: A random idea would be to square it and then compare to the definition of the Gamma function. Of course transform variable to polar coordinates or so...

Comment: I'm a little too tired to try it right now, but you might be able to get somewhere by mimicking Example 2.1.5 in [these notes](http://www.jeanphilippeovarlez.com/Homepage_de_Ovarlez_Jean-Philippe/Publications_files/MELLIN.pdf).  See also [this question from M.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21852/techniques-to-compute-complex-integrals-over-infinite-contours).

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer as it does not provide an explicit expression for $f(x)$.

Multiply your equation with $(-s)^n/n!$ and sum over $n$, then you obtain
$$(\mathcal{L}f)(s)=\int_0^\infty f(x)e^{- sx}\,dx = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-s)^n}{\sqrt{n!}}.$$

Inverting the Laplace transform yields
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{-i\infty}^{i\infty} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-s)^n}{\sqrt{n!}} e^{s x}\,ds
=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-i y)^n}{\sqrt{n!}} e^{iy x}\,dy.$$

Comment: Ah, that reminds me of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform

Comment: @Gerenuk: you can also do it via the inverse of the Mellin transform. I believe that it is also not possible to invert the transform in that case...